# Code reuse of .NET 4.0 DLL (that uses Nuget packages) with .NET CORE

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I spent a few days writing a class library of .DLL functions in .NET 4.0.

Now I want to call it from an AWS Lambda function using .NET Core. 
Apparently, we cannot reference from CORE to .NET Framework; get this error:

[image]

In my class library, I used every Nuget package I could to save time and make my code small. So even if I convert my class library to CORE, I would have to now rewrite each of the Nuget packages?

Seems like we really don't have code re-use here. Am I missing some shortcut here, or it's just going to be a big pain? If each Nuget is open source, then I would have to get the code, then build a .CORE version of it?

I read this Q/A but didn't really give any solution yet: [Converting a .Net dll to a .Net Core dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951314/converting-a-net-dll-to-a-net-core-dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the nuget packages are netstandard (1.x/2.x) compliant so there is big chance that you can use them in your project if you convert your project to .NET Standard library. For example [Autofac](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/) is compatible with .NET Framework 4.5 and also with .NET Standard 1.1 (.NET Standard Library >= 1.6).

[image]

From the screenshot we can see that your project is not .NET Standard compliant. The difference is that you have used .NET Framework template for project like:
[image]

While you should be using .NET Standard template:
[image]

If your project is not using some windows native functions there is high probability that you can just convert it to .NET Standard project with little or no change at all.

Here is how to create new project that is .NET Standard compliant:
[image]
Also, from screenshot I can see that you are targeting .NET Core 1.0 so you have to make sure that your project is targeting correct .NET Standard version (I know that this can be confusing now). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is a list of .NET Framework / .NET Core compatibility with .NET Standard.
For .NET Core 1.0 your library should be targeting .NET Standard 1.6:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on ".NET Standard", I haven't heard of that yet.

Comment: You will probably want to read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/) one also. :)

Comment: For example, I was using this package: https://libraries.io/nuget/Freezer. 
I created a new TestCore Class Library, and ran the "Install-Package Freezer -Version 1.0.1.5". It shows up in the project references, but says it cannot be resolved.  I going to watch some YouTube videos today, to see I I can wrap my head around all this.

Comment: Unfortunately, Freezer is not .NET Standard compat library and that means that you can't use it in .NET Core project. Usually, on the nuget you can see what are framework dependencies eg. [Autofac](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/) is .NET 4.5 and Standard 1.1 compatibile. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i believe that you can also create a nuget package from your existing DLL, then it works to :)

(if i am not mistaken, not 100% sure though)

Comment: Yes, I've seen people discuss creating nuget packages, but not sure how that solves the problem.  My DLL is using at least one Nuget package that is not compatible.